# Single Sign On using Mono

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4, mono, monodevelop

We have a couple of Authentication Services hosted on IIS (used by a couple of sites hosted on IIS). I couldn't move them on Linux as they have been implemented using Windows Identity Foundation which is not supported on Mono. I am building a MVC4 application from scratch on Mono. Is there a way to implement Single Sign on by consuming the Security Token?

Please let me know if you need more information on this.

Comment: You should not use one question to actually ask two. Please consider moving the second question to a new one and have the content removed here.

Comment: For your second question, the exception message is pretty self-explanatory:  You have a duplicate key.  Without seeing the code no one can tell you anything more than that (and even if you posted your code, unless you know where the error occurs we most likely couldn't help).  Try stepping through your code in the debugger to see where the duplicate key is coming from.

Comment: If it works well in Mono for windows but not debian, then it means that the mono version used in debian is older, please upgrade your debian mono. BTW I agree with Sascha (so I'm downvoting your question until you split it in two, and then I will upvote)

Comment: Hi Sascha/knocte, I have removed my second question. Sorry about that.

Comment: Hi Tim, thank you for the reply. I have been unable to step through the code from Monodeveloper. Using published code works fine, but when I run from monodevelop I get NullReferenceException at GetCustomEncoderFromConfig. I have tried all the solutions posted online, but don't work for me. It works only when I start using  "Run Item". I have pretty much tried everything in last 2 weeks :(